# compareTo() method setup between two classes

Tags: java

I am trying to implement the `compareTo()` method on one of my classes but am having trouble with the 'steps' to get there and just need an explanation to what I am doing wrong.

I want to use the `compareTo()` method to compare a *place* and to a specific *thing's place*.

I'm getting error: 
**the method compareTo(Venue) is undefined for the type Venue** 
 on my first line of the `compareTo()` method.

I think this is happening because I am not correctly inheriting `Place(String name)` from the `Place class`, which I think is needed to be able to actually compare 2 places.

I am not sure how this is done, and an explanation to what is/should be going on would further clarify

**Class 1:**

```
public class Place {
    // the name of the place
    private String name;
    // invariant: name != null 

    // Creates a new place with the given name.
    public Place(String name){
    if (name != null){
        this.name = name;   
    } else 
        throw new NullPointerException();
    }

    //returns the name of a place
    public String getName(){
        return name;
    }
}
```

**Class 2:**

```
public class Thing implements Comparable<Thing>{
    // the name of the place at which the thing occurs
    private Place place;

    // Creates a new thing for the given place
     public Thing(Place place) {
        if (place == null){
            throw new NullPointerException("Place cannot be null");
        }
        this.place = place;
    }

    // Returns the place of the thing.
    public Place getPlace() {
        return place;
    }

    public int compareTo(Thing thing) {
        if (getPlace().compareTo(thing.getPlace()) > 0){
            return 1;

        } else if //..rest of compareTo method  
        }
    }
}
```

*excuse poor wording as I am finding it difficult to put my thought process into sentences that make 'java sense'*

Comment: You never wrote a `compareTo` method for `Place`. What would `getPlace().compareTo(thing.getPlace())` do?

Comment: You should avoid using `compareTo()` and use a comparator instead.  This is good design.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `Place` class needs a compareTo() method if you want to use it in your `Thing` class.

```
public class Place implements Comparable<Place> {
// the name of the place
private String name;
// invariant: name != null 

// Creates a new place with the given name.
public Place(String name){
if (name != null){
    this.name = name;   
} else 
    throw new NullPointerException();
}

//returns the name of a place
public String getName(){
    return name;
}

public int compareTo(Place other) {
    // do something here
}
```

}

In your code the compiler doesn't know what to do when you call `getPlace().compareTo(...)` since that method hasn't been defined in the Place class, which getPlace() returns.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a custom comparator inside the `Place` class and use it to for comparing `Place`s by their `name`:

```
public class Place {
    private String name;

    public Place(String name) {
        if (name != null) {
            this.name = name;   
        } else {
            throw new NullPointerException();
        }
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public static Comparator<Place> PlaceNameComparator = new Comparator<Place>() {
        public int compare(Place place1, Place place2) {
            String placeName1 = place1.getName();
            String placeName2 = place2.getName();

            return placeName1.compareTo(placeName2);
        }
    };
}
```

You can use the custom comparator like this:

```
Place[] places = new Place[3];
places[0] = new Place("New York");
places[1] = new Place("Texas");
places[2] = new Place("Denver");

Arrays.sort(places, Place.PlaceNameComparator);
for (int i=0; i < places.length; ++i)
    System.out.println(places[i].getName());
```

**Output:**

```
Denver
New York
Texas
```

I prefer using comparators strongly over overriding `compareTo()`, because the latter limits your class to comparing based on one behavior.  On the other hand, you can create as many comparators as you have comparisons.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add Comparable interface to Place or check directly the value of name.

Something like

```
public class Place implements Comparable {
    public int compareTo(Place place) {
        return name.compareTo(place.getName());
    }
}
```

or change the Thing compareTo

```
public class Thing implements Comparable<Thing> {
    public int compareTo(Thing other) {
        return place.getName().compareTo(other.getPlace().getName());
    }
}
```

This is a minimal code. You have to check for null values.